# Error: Table tablename for model modelname was not found in datasource default with non-default database

Tags: cakephp, model

This is with CakePHP 2.4. I have a table (table1) which is connected to three others (tables 2 to 4) through a [hasMany through](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany-through-the-join-model) connection. All four tables are in a non-default database. Although I'm using hasMany from tables 2-4 to table 1 and in the class for table1

```
public $belongsTo = array('table2', 'table3', 'table4');
```

When I try and display the view for table1 I get the error

```
Table table1 for model model1 was not found in datasource default
```

So it's looking in datasource default even though all four tables have are in the non-default database (specified using $useDbConfig).

Answer (score 0):

Although the documentation doesn't say why you would want to [specify the classname](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#belongsto), even if it follows the naming convention, this appears to be the solution:

```
public $belongsTo = array('table2', => array(
                                            'className' => 'table2'),
                          'table3'=> array(
                                            'className' => 'table3'),

                          'table4'=> array(
                                            'className' => 'table4'));
```